# Adding items into an array - Separately

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ejs

**Goal: Click a button and have ingredients added to an array as separate items.**

Current Set Up:

```
    <% currentUser.ingredients.forEach(function(items){ %> 
   <p class='ingredients'>  <%= items %> </p>
    <% }) %>
```

This gives: Blueberries Mango Lemon Juice

I'd then like to be able to add the ingredients as separate items to an array by clicking a button:

```
var allIngredients = []

$("#makeList").click(function() {

allIngredients.push($(".ingredients").text())
console.log(allIngredients)

});
```

This prints ["Blueberrys Mango Lemon Juice"]

The issue is it is all one item not separate items.

**What to I need to change to make them separate items?**

Comment: try adding using .split()

Comment: allIngredients.concat($(".ingredients")) // assuming $ingredients returns an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over `$('.ingredients')`

```
var allIngredients = [];

$("#makeList").click(function() {

    $(".ingredients").each(function() {
        allIngredients.push($(this).text());
    });

    console.log(allIngredients);

});
```

Comment: You're a hero. Thank you!

Comment: You beat me by a few minutes :) But this won't give the desired result for multi-word values.

Answer (score 1):

A mere split or looping over text nodes wouldn't give expected result if a value can be multi-word. For a robust solution, surround the rendered values by some html tag

```js
<% currentUser.ingredients.forEach(function(items){ %> 
   <p class='ingredients'>  <span class="ingredient"><%= items %></span> </p>
<% }) %>
```

```js
var allIngredients = []

$("#makeList").click(function() {

    $(".ingredients").find('.ingredient').each(function() {
        allIngredients.push($(this).text());
    });
    console.log(allIngredients)

});
```